# how to replace html code (read: odd Characters) from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I compiled an extensive batch script to download an rss file from a server, and download the images referenced in there to a local path. the next step would be to modify the image source inside my downloaded rss file. (eventually it would serve for a digital display solution which is only connected to the LAN)

I've found a working way how to do this by calling a vbs script:

in my batch I have:

```
cscript replace.vbs "rss.cfm" "http://blabla.com/images/thumb" "RSS-script/images/normal"
```

the vbs script contains:

```
Const ForReading = 1    
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewText  'WriteLine adds extra CR/LF
objFile.Close
```

unfortunately for my digital signage software, this is not enough. What does work is to create a different tag for the image. So I've modified my script to replace some tags and code, but because of the strange characters the script crashes.

So I would need to replace this identical string: (for the prefix, and something similar as a suffix)

```
<description><![CDATA[<img src="http://blabla.com/images/thumb
```

with

```
<image><url>RSS-script/images/normal
```

and for the suffix I should replace `.jpg"`

with

```
.jpg</url></image><description><![CDATA[<
```

I've found many solutions who say to usa a caret ^ escape character in front of every symbol, but also this doesn't help me a lot because there is also a space between img and src. I've tried single quotes, back quotes, without quotes. And in fact don't even an idea what I'm doing: My scripting capabilities are limited to the basic explanations I find here or on ss64.com

My original rss file looks like this:

```
<item>                      
<title>this is the title of the item</title>
<description><![CDATA[<img src="http://www.blabla.com/images/thumb_xyz.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" vspace="5" alt="picture 1" title="description title" width="200">
<p>
STORY CONTENT
</p>
]]></description> 
<pubDate>Tue, 19 Nov 2013 18:15:38 +0100</pubDate>
<category>HEADLINES</category>
</item>
```

and my final result should be: (this is tested and working)

```
<item>
<title>this is the title of the item</title>
<image><url>RSS-script/images/normal_xyz.jpg</url></image>
<description><![CDATA[< align="left" hspace="5" vspace="5" alt="picture 1" title="description title" width="200">
<p>
STORY CONTENT
</p>
]]></description> 
<pubDate>Tue, 19 Nov 2013 18:15:38 +0100</pubDate>
<category>HEADLINES</category>
</item>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, and sorry for the long post. At least I think all the info is here..

Vik

Comment: Your problem seems to be with quoting - if you post the actual source and what you actually need then someone may be able to help you.

Comment: thanx for looking at my post, the actual source is posted where it says "My original rss file looks like this" and what I actually need is below that.

Comment: You said that you have modified the RSS file using VBS.  That's not the actual source then.

Comment: No sorry I said I've found a way to replace the file path in the rss using vbs, but unfortunately that solution was not sufficient. so with the same script I wanted to replace the string `<description><![CDATA[<img src="http://blabla.com/images/thumb` but that didn't work because (I think) of the atypical characters and blankspace.
 
what I posted below is the original rss how I took it from the web.
below that one is what I should finally result with.

Comment: Is `<![CDATA[` in the original source?  It doesn't look like it should be there.

Comment: no Idea what cdata means but as it was there I didn't think much of it

Comment: How important is the date and time format?

Comment: I mean you are changing it from the 19th to the 18th and altering the timestamp.  What rules are you using for that?

Comment: ah no that was just my mistake I probably copied another item time and should have been the same. what a sharp eye you have..

Comment: You've given an example of what the file is, and what it should be.  The date and time stamp is different, there is a  width="200" missing from the changed file, and so I'm trying to figure out which changes are the right ones.

Comment: ah yes, so as I explained the timestamp should remain. and the width is not so important. I only described half of my problem here, as said  before, this is only the prefix. the suffix is similar and should be easy once I can figure out how to do the prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will modify the example RSS source in `file.rss` and redirect it to a `file2.rss`.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
type "file.rss" |repl "(.*<!\[CDATA\[<)img src=\x22.*\/thumb_(.*\.jpg)\x22(.*)" "<image><url>RSS-script/images/normal_$2</url></image>\r\n$1$3" x >"file2.rss"
```

Comment: This is fantastic, I don't understand anything of the code but it seems to work like a charm. I'll test the outcome now on my digital signage system.

Comment: hmm.. it does not seem to work when I put this line of code inside my main batch file. I tested it in a file called test.bat with only this line, which went perfect. but placing it at the end of my main file does nothing to file2.rss. If I place a `start test.bat` it works

Comment: The way you are executing it must have changed, or it is not being executed. Also try deleting file2.rss and see if a new one is created - and if it is the same then the format of the source file has changed.  FWIW the repl.bat uses the two search and replace terms, using regular expressions.

Comment: a new version of file2 is created but the content is the same as the source file. For as far as I know the source file format is still the same. except for the fact that I didn't publish the exact url, but this has no impact on the way you created the script. However as I explained, it works by calling your line of code from an external batch file. this is good enough for me. 

Thanks a lot for your help
Vik